# Google Maps and Python

Tags: python, google-maps

I am building an GPS tracker application in Python. How can I use Google Maps in my application?

Comment: Not a proper question. How do you use any API? You read the documentation and do what it says.

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: i want to track the user!!is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Google maps is a client-side web application, meaning it can only run in a web browser.  You will have to use a web server with your python application (using mod_wsgi or the like and some type of web library like tornado or cherrypy).  The web server will serve HTML and javascript files which may make use of Google Maps.

Comment: ok..i see!isnt there any other way...i.e without using a web server?

Comment: You may be able to find an embeddable maps product, but it's not possible with Google Maps, short of embedding a web browser in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you'd need a web server. There are various network APIs to google-maps including this one http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html, and python can access those APIs using urllib and/or httplib

Try googling "python google map" - it seems there are some python packages already out there which encapsulate these APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I do know there is a Client Library created for Python.

You can download it with `pip install -U googlemaps`

More information can be found here: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python
The documentation here: https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/2.4.4/